# I created a notes app in android studio but it doesn't save the note on clicking the save button. There's no errors shown in gradle build or in logcat

Tags: android-studio, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

https://github.com/prasaddd77/Make-A-Note
This is the source code for my application.

When I click on the save button after adding a note title and a note description it goes nowhere, nothing happens. When I click on the save note button it should take me back to the main activity where I can see the note I just saved with the title a time stamp and a delete button icon on the right.

None of that is happening and I can't seem to figure out what the problem is since the logcat isn't showing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the apostrophes here:

```
("noteType".equals("Edit"))
```

What you do here is compare if the actual texts are the same. They are not obviously.

What you need is to check the variables.

Comment: I did that but still when I write a note title and a note description and click on save notes, nothing happens. Is there a problem with the room file?